# Server site configuration of git

Tags: git

I've been trying to learn Git in the past two/three weeks.

What port does Git run on by default? Is there a specific port to unlock on a home router to get outside commits working if the router is protected by a firewall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git supports:

- SSH
- HTTP/S
- Git protocol
- Local protocol

Depending on your needs you have to use one of these protocols. Have a look at the section "[The Protocols](http://progit.org/book/ch4-1.html)" in the book Pro Git for a detailed explanation about these protocols.